# "The HTTP request is unauthorized..." when connecting as domain user

Tags: c#, wcf, active-directory

***Description***

I have a WCF web service and a WCF client, running on the same machine. I'm using windows authentication. I'm trying to connect from the client, as a *chosen* domain user:

```
var client = new MyService.ServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWORD", "DOMAIN");
client.ReceiveData("hello");
```

Unfortunately the last line results in the error:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'
```

How can i resolve this?

***Note***:

**This works on a different machine in a different domain. So it's probably a setting on my machine**.

**This does not happen for local users:**

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("LOCALUSER", "PASSWORD", "");
```

**I get the same error when i enter the wrong password for a local user.**

**This also does not happen when i am already logged in as the domain user, and don't specify credentials**:

```
var client = new MyService.ServiceClient();
client.ReceiveData("hello");
```

**When i remove NTLM from [Authetication > Windows Authetication >
Providers...], then i instead get the puzzling error:**

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'.
```

**client App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyService/Service.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                contract="MyService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When you use windows authentication, the server should also exist in a Windows domain that uses the Kerberos protocol as its domain controller. If the server is not on a Kerberos supported domain, or if the Kerberos system fails. In short, if you use windows authentication, the client and server are best in the same windows domain.

Comment: @DingPeng how is providing same user, password, domain that i login to the machine with, different from using the default credentials of the same logged in user? the system is on the same domain as the user. does me being able to login to the machine with a domain user, mean that i'm on a Kerberos supported domain?

Comment: @DingPeng i just found out that it seems to work when the application pool user of the web service is set to the domain user, instead of a local admin account. so it looks like a problem with user rights